# How to add a second web app with jetty alongside with geoserver?

Tags: jetty, geoserver

I deployed the Platform Independent Binary of GeoServer on ubuntu. To launch geoserver, I would just run this script /usr/share/geoserver/bin/startup.sh
So no jetty is actually installed. Geoserver web app can be accessbile via http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web

I wonder how I can configure a second web app which takes this path http://localhost:8080/upload/index.html
Ideally, I would like python and perhaps PHP are supported.

Any tips is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any other **war** files to *geoserver_dir*`/webaps/` and Jetty will unpack and run them like any other servlet.

I have no idea how you would add python and PHP to that set up. Maybe you would be better off looking at running tomcat and apache and using the GeoServer war file there.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The problem is that it won't be a war file though. It can be a static html page which allows users to upload photos....or it can be a web app built with django.

Comment: then you definitely need apache and tomcat